# VBA: Import xls to Access Allowing User to Specify xls to Import

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010...

I am trying to write/find a script that performs the following steps:

1. Run script
2. Dialogue window opens (essentially Windows Explorer) allowing user to navigate to and select an xls for importing
3. User selects xls
4. Access imports this xls into a table called Import
5. Script ends

I have found a snippet to allow for a file Explorer window to open:

```
    Dim f    As Object
    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    f.Show
```

But I can't figure out how to join this to something like:

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Import", "FILEPATH", True, ""
```

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff196794.aspx) is an application object with a few components including title of dialog window, initial default path, file type filter to guide users on correct type and one important item is its variant array, `.SelectedItems()` which you use to pull the string of selected file(s).

```
Dim f  As Object
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)

f.AllowMultiSelect = False
f.Title = "Title of Dialog Window"
f.InitialFileName = "C:\Set\Default\Path"
f.Filters.Clear
f.Filters.Add "PDF files", "*.pdf"
f.FilterIndex = 1

If f.Show = -1 Then
    strFilePath = f.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   'The user pressed Cancel.
    MsgBox "No file Selected", vbExclamation
    strFilePath = Null        
End if

Set fd = Nothing
```

From there you can pass strFilePath into your import command:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "Import", strFilePath, True, ""
```